# Picamera module doesn't work in raspberry pi2b with error "No data received from sensor"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

I tried two cameras, but They didn't work.
I'm using old Raspbian (ver.5.4.72) to build a robot ([https://www.adeept.com/raspclaws_p0124.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk7iU.jpg)).

[My raspberry pi 2b and robotkit's module and picamera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk7iU.jpg)

This is my first write and I am not good at English. I'm sorry if there is a mistake.

> My Environment

- raspberry pi 2b
- picamera(Non-genuine one)
- Robotkit's modules (Maybe that's not the problem)
- Rasibian 5.4.72
- Python Varsion : 2.7.16

> Picamera status

- Camera's light is shining.
- Interface of Legacy camera option is enabled.
- Result of `vcgencmd get_camera` is *supported=1 detected=1*.
- Result of `raspistill -o test.jpg`;
  *Camera control callback
  cmd=0x4f525245mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all
  connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board.*
  I checked all of them, but I'm still stacking.
- I tried other cameras, but none of them didn't work with same as this error.
- `sudo bash -c "echo core_freq=250" /boot/config.txt`, Make Raspberry pi stable, but it didn't help.
  What should I do to solve the problems? If you have questions or mistakes, please let me know.

Once my goal was to run webServer.py ([on this web site](https://github.com/adeept/Adeept_RaspClaws), to run the robot which I refered before.) successfully.
When I try running below;
`sudo python3 webServer.py`
Reply comes with

*File "/home/pi/adeept_raspclaws/server/camera_opencv.py", line 421, in frames

if img.all == None:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'*
I looked up to the Line 421 of camera_opencv.py, There are codes that read the CURRENT image of the camera.
So, I'm positive that this errors is caused by the broken camera.

Comment: Does your picamera working if you try this raspistill -o test.jpg?

Comment: No it doesn't working.

Comment: How do you connect two cameras to two ports? Which port?

Comment: I replaced and installed them.